# MySQL Insert Statement for Many to Many Junction Table for All Records of 1 table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, many-to-many, sql-insert

I have a many to many relationship between two tables.

**The first table:** Users: (ID, Name, Active, etc)

**The second table:**
  Projects: (ProjectID, Description, DueDate, etc).

**The third table** is obviously a junction table between the two for a many-to-many relationship, since a user can have many projects and a project can have many users. (ID, UserID, ProjectID)

My issue is creating a clean insert statement for adding a user to all projects at once. How can this be done in 1 single sql statement. I am using MySQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the `<UserID>` beforehand you can do:

```
INSERT INTO project_user
SELECT <UserID>,ProjectID
FROM projects;
```

This will insert a row for each `ProjectID` that has always the same `UserID`.